# Block texture load only when placed, but not in inventory

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've read some other 'similar' questions but their problems is exactly the opposite. I've also read the docs but they won't provide anything useful to this problem.

When I `/give` myself the block, it shows a missing texture in my inventory as a item. But when I place it, its texture is shown in the world as a block.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Main mod class:

```java
package com.byethost8.code2828.mcmods.chemc;

import net.minecraft.block.AbstractBlock;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.OreBlock;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.block.material.MaterialColor;
import net.minecraft.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.item.Item.Properties;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;

@Mod(CheMC_.modid)
public class CheMC_ {

    public static final String modid = "chemc";

    public static OreBlock ore_lithium = (OreBlock) new OreBlock(
        AbstractBlock.Properties
            .create(Material.ROCK, MaterialColor.PINK_TERRACOTTA)
            .harvestLevel(1)
            .hardnessAndResistance(1, 1)
            .setLightLevel(
                light -> {
                    return 1;
                }
            )
    )
    .setRegistryName("chemc", "lithium_ore");
    public static BlockItem i_ore_lithium = (BlockItem) new BlockItem(
        ore_lithium,
        new Properties().group(ItemGroup.BUILDING_BLOCKS)
    )
    .setRegistryName(ore_lithium.getRegistryName());
    public static Block block_lithium = new Block(
        AbstractBlock.Properties
            .create(Material.IRON, MaterialColor.PINK_TERRACOTTA)
            .harvestLevel(1)
            .hardnessAndResistance(1.2F, 1)
            .setLightLevel(
                light -> {
                    return 1;
                }
            )
    )
    .setRegistryName("chemc", "lithium_block");
    public static BlockItem i_block_lithium = (BlockItem) new BlockItem(
        block_lithium,
        new Properties().group(ItemGroup.BUILDING_BLOCKS)
    )
    .setRegistryName(block_lithium.getRegistryName());

    public CheMC_() {
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext
            .get()
            .getModEventBus()
            .addListener(this::setup);
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    private void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {}

    // You can use EventBusSubscriber to automatically subscribe events on the
    // contained class (this is subscribing to the MOD
    // Event bus for receiving Registry Events)
    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
    public static class RegistryEvents {

        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onBlocksRegistry(
            final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> blockRegistryEvent
        ) {
            // register a new block here
            blockRegistryEvent
                .getRegistry()
                .registerAll(ore_lithium, block_lithium);
        }
    }
}
```

Some codes are removed to make the main problem clear.
Following texts only will say about Lithium Block, but same things apply for Lithium Ore.
Model File:

```json
{
    "parent": "block/cube_all",
    "textures": {
        "all": "chemc:block/lithium_block"
    }
}
```

Folder structure of src/main/resources:
[image: Folder Structure]

Blockstate:

```json
{
    "variants": {
        "": [
            { "model": "chemc:block/lithium_block" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe that I was stupid enough to register a `Item` and do nothing to `assets/chemc/resources/models/item/` folder. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845220/block-texture-is-loaded-successfully-but-the-blockitem-texture-isnt-minecra) for more. I have the exactly same problem as that OP.